# Cannot find meteor module

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am trying to run a meteor app but keep getting the `Cannot find module error` when I try to import one of my files.

My folder directory:

`/app/client/imports/api/tasks.js`

`/app/server/main.js`

In my `main.js` I am trying to import `tasks.js`:

`import '../client/imports/api/tasks.js';`

This throws the error `Error: Cannot find module '../client/imports/api/tasks.js'`.

My `tasks.js`:

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

export const Tasks = new Mongo.collection('tasks');
```

Does anyone know what might be going on?

Comment: Do you export a module in `tasks.js`?

Comment: Hi - yes - see my edited question above.

Comment: I have never used meteor, but should you not give your import a name? `import Tasks from '../client/imports/api/tasks.js';`

Comment: That still throws the same 'Cannot find module' error. also, fyi, i'm following the meteor tutorial: https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/collections

Comment: Hmm.. Like I said, I have never used meteor. Just thought it may be like ES6. I am out of ideas, hope you come right! :)

Comment: Usually imports is not within client. Something is wrong with the folder structure. Not advisable to import from client folder into a server file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't import a `/client` based file from the `/server` side. Files stored under a `client` directory are only bundled and made available to the client side of the application (the part that runs in a users browser). Files stored under a `server` directory are only bundled and made available on the server side, running via Node.

Get rid of the `/client` prefix from your `tasks.js` reference, to be able to reference the import from both sides. For example:

**/app/imports/api/tasks.js**

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
const Tasks = new Mongo.Collection('tasks');
export default Tasks;
```

Then in `/app/client/main.js` or `/app/server/main.js`, you could reference the `tasks.js` file like:

```
import Tasks from '/imports/api/tasks.js';
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in file structure.
Your ***imports/*** folder should be on the same level with ***client/*** and ***server/***.